# How to ignore a 'shared' NUnit test in a base class for a specific derived class

Tags: c#, nunit

I've got a test suite that exercises a feature in a number of different 'scenarios.' In each scenario, certain facts about the feature must always be true, and in addition there's some extra scenario-specific things to check.

I've structured this using inheritance in my test classes like so:

```
abstract class BaseTestScenario
- Common [Test]s for all scenarios

class Scenario1 : BaseTestScenario
- [Test]s specific to scenario 1

class Scenario2 : BaseTestScenario
- [Test]s specific to scenario 2

... etc ...
```

This is working quite nicely, but now I have some test failures to deal with. Ideally, I'd be able to mark the specific failures with `[Ignore]` while I'm resolving them, so that everyone can run the remaining tests without worrying about the known failures.

Is there any way to mark one of my common `[Test]`s with `[Ignore]` in a specific scenario, without affecting the other scenarios?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using ignore, you could use `Assume.That`.

```
[Test]
public override void SomeTest()
{
    // Run some logic to determine if the test should be skipped.
    bool skipThisTest = true;

    Assume.That(skipThisTest, "This test doesn't apply here.");
}
```

The result is that the test won't run (it will appear Inconclusive (blue) in Visual Studio Test Explorer).

Do note this also works if you call `Assume.That` within the class constructor.

Comment: Clever use of Inconclusive result!